# Friendly names for AWS internal ELBs

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have some internal load balancers in AWS, and they have very long addresses, like

internal-abcdeskhdfksdfkjhsdkjfhksjhdfkjsf-1878388.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com

We have vpn setup so that we have access to the load balancer from our browsers. Is there a way to have a "friendlier" name for such a load balancer? I'd be happy with using something like foo.mydomain.com, where mydomain.com is a public hosted zone, or setting up a private hosting zone. I tried adding a subdomain with alias pointing to the internal ELB, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working with the following:

For a Route53 hosted zone that was created for a domain (say, mydomain.com), I created a record set. I used the following parameters:

`Name = mysubdomain
Type = A - IPV4 address
Alias = Yes
Target = internal-abcdeskhdfksdfkjhsdkjfhksjhdfkjsf-1878388.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

Where the target is the internal load balancer dns name. This allowed me to address the target as mysubdomain.mydomain.com .

dig resolves it to an internal ip address, so as long as I have network access, this works. i.e. this works for both private, and public load balancers.

Comment: This solution worked. This configuration is no-different from how you would configure the DNS for the public ALB. The difference here is that you can only hit and validate the ALB from the allowed subnets.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CNAME` record in your DNS (eg Amazon Route 53) to point to a load balancer.

See: [Configure a Custom Domain Name for Your Classic Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html) (The same should apply to an Application Load Balancer.)

You could configure Route 53 to resolve only within a domain, or you could use a public DNS, since the `CNAME` *should* then restart with the internal ELB DNS name. (But I'd have to test it.)